# Hibernate CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE transcient exception on update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I use Spring boot with H2 in memory database with

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

and `Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}`

I have an object entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_OBJECT")
public class ObjectEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "IDT_OBJECT")
    private Long id; 

    @Column(name = "NAME",length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    // from org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;
    @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_OBJECT", referencedColumnName = "IDT_CATEGORY")
    private CategoryEntity category;
}
```

and a CategoryEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_CATEGORY")
public class CategoryEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "IDT_CATEGORY")
    private Long id; 

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
}
```

I have this objectService

```
@Transactional(rollbackOn = Exception.class)
public void saveOrUpdateObject(ObjectForm object) {

   ObjectEntity objEntity = null;

   if(object.getId() != null) {
     objEntity = daoObject.findById(object.getId())
   }

   if(objEntity == null) {
     objEntity = new ObjectEntity();

     // we can't change the name
     objEntity.setName(object.getName);
   }

   CategoryEntity catEntity = objEntity.getCategory();

   if(catEntity == null) {
         catEntity = new CategoryEntity();
   }
   catEntity.setName(object.getCategoryName())

   objEntity.setCategory(catEntity);

   // execute sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate()
   daoObject.saveOrUpdate(objEntity);

}
```

This code perfectly work when I create the object, but I get a transcient error when update with a different category

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.appli.entity.ObjectEntity.category -> com.appli.entity.CategoryEntity
```

of course if I save the CategoryEntity into my service with `daoCategory.saveOrUpdate(catEntity)` before save the `ObjectEntity` that works but that shouldn't be necessary with Cascade SAVE_UPDATE

But also just if I change CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE by persistance.Cascade

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {javax.persistence.CascadeType.PERSIST, javax.persistence.CascadeType.REFRESH, javax.persistence.CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_OBJECT", referencedColumnName = "IDT_CATEGORY")
private CategoryEntity category;
```

it works for create and update without change a line of the service. `@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)` also works

I though  `@Cascade(hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)` was the same than `cascade = {javax.persistence.CascadeType.PERSIST, javax.persistence.CascadeType.REFRESH, javax.persistence.CascadeType.MERGE}`

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should always use persist for TRANSIENT entities and merge for DETACHED ones.

The saveOrUpdate shortcomings (when passing a detached entity snapshot to a Session already managing this entity) had lead to the merge operation,  Please check this link: https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/03/05/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/

Comment: I think that not explain why hibernate SAVE_UPDATE cause transcient exception but replacing javax.persistence{persist,refresh,merge) works perfectly.I have other hibernate project and never have an issue with SAVE_UPDATE I really don't get why on this spring boot project on a really basic association I have this issue :/ but thx for the link.

Comment: for me it's an hibernate 5.0.12 issue